# Plane equation (weird form question)

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

So I have this equation in a homework:

$P_1 = \{Q \in \Bbb R^3|\ (Q\ +\ (-1,1,2)) \in  \langle(2,-1,-1),(1,1,0) \rangle\}$

So, my question is, how can this be a plane?, the dot product is going to be a number right?, am I missing something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plane here is defined by the set $\{Q\in\mathbb{R}^3\}$ where $Q$ satisfies the given conditions.

There isn't a dot product in that description. In this case
$$
\langle(2,-1,-1),(1,1,0) \rangle
$$
indicates all linear combinations of the 2 vectors i.e.
$$
\alpha(2,-1,-1) + \beta(1,1,0) \quad \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}
$$
This notation can be used with any number of vectors e.g.
$$
\langle(2,-1,-1) \rangle
$$
would indicate a line ( all 'linear cobinations' $\alpha(2,-1,-1)$)

Thus your plane is given by the set
$$
Q+(-1,1,2) \in\{ \alpha(2,-1,-1) + \beta(1,1,0)\}\quad \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}
$$
or
$$
\{ \alpha(2,-1,-1) + \beta(1,1,0) - (-1,1,2)\}\quad \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}
$$

Comment: +1 I'd surprisingly never seen this usage of the notation before. I'd seen inner products and probably would have assumed a dot like the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol

$$\langle(2,-1,-1),(1,1,0) \rangle$$

is often used to indicate also the span of the vectors thus it corresponds to the plane through the origin

$$P(t,s)=t(2,-1,-1)+s(1,1,0)$$

and the plane $P_1$ is in the form

$$P_1(t,s)=v_0+t(2,-1,-1)+s(1,1,0)$$

with

$$v_0=(1,-1,-2)+t_0(2,-1,-1)+s_0(1,1,0)$$

for some $t_0,r_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and notably for $t_0=s_0=0$

$$P_1(t,s)=(1,-1,-2)+t(2,-1,-1)+s(1,1,0)$$

Comment: For a full answer you also have to take into account the $(-1,1,2)$

Comment: oh, that makes sense, the thing is that in class we always use that notation to express the point product.

Comment: @Henry Yes it is an affine plane thus the given here is the plane through the origin of course.

Comment: Gimusi.Question: The general plane should be: \vec r= \vec r_0 +t(2,-1,1)+s(1,1,0), where \vec r_0=(a,b,c) \in R^3.Note that {Q+(-1,1,2))=R^3.Am I wrong?;))

Comment: @PeterSzilas yes of course it is a plane not through the origin, I’ve given the subspace part to clarify the doubt of the OP about the symbolism used.

Comment: Gimusi: it a plane with any \vec r_0 =(a,b,c) not just (a,b,c)=(-1,1,2).Funny question.Am I wrong?

Comment: @PeterSzilas Yes the general plane is in the form $r_0+t(2,-1,-1)+s(1,1,0)$ with $r_0=(1,-1,-2)+t_0(2,-1,-1)+s_0(1,1,0)$ for some $t_0,s_0$, in particulare by $t_0=s_0=0$ we have $r_0=(1,-1,-2)$.

Comment: @PeterSzilas I've clarified this point also in the answer in order to avoid misunderstandings.